# Blender 2.8 and Caustics in YafaRay and POV

Tags: caustics

Hello dear Blenderheads,

It's a very technical problem here:

I'm working on a project and I need Caustics

Looks like it's very hard to obtain good Caustics in Cycles due to the nature of the rendering engine, so I'm looking for other renderers to fake a "Caustics Pass" and then composite all together with the rest of my scene

There are tutorials around the web that show how to render Caustics in YafaRay, and I like the idea but before I install YafaRay, Python and Addons on my Windows workstation, I'd like to be sure YafaRay and its Plugin are compatible with Blender 2.8x, 'cause can't find information about this

In case of YafaRay and 2.8x don't go very well together, is it a viable solution to use Persist Of Vision? The plugin is available in the Addons

Can i render animations with Yafaray of POV?

Any help is much appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

[LuxCoreRender](https://luxcorerender.org/gallery/) is able to use bidirectional path tracing with CPU rendering that is more suitable to render caustics. It is also free and open source and its integration to Blender is alright. It is worth having a look.

[image]

It takes a long time, but it works. You need to select Bidir engine and Metropolis sampling seems to work best:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Lux is very easy to setup, very imtegrated with Blender and lightning fast!